# congruence hermitian matrix $I_n$. Conclusions.

Tags: linear-algebra

Hermitian matrix $A\in\mathbb{C}^{n,n}$ is congruent to matrix $I_n$. Then:
a. $\forall_{\overrightarrow{x}\in\mathbb{C}^n\setminus\{0\}} \overrightarrow{x}^HA\overrightarrow{x} > 0$
b. all eigenvalues of matrix A are positive real numbers
c. $A=I_n$

c.  It is not true.
From congruency we conclude: $A=C^HI_nC=C^HC$ where $C$ is some nonsingular matrix. $
 \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
5 & 0  \\
0 & 5  \\
 \end{array} \right]$
 Then $A= \left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
25 & 0  \\
0 & 25  \\
 \end{array} \right]\neq I_n$

I have no idea how to solve b. and a.  Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $A=C^HC$ with $C$ non-singular, then for all non-zero $x\in\mathbb{C}^n$ we have
$$ x^HAx=x^H(C^HC)x=(Cx)^HCx>0 $$
since $C$ is non-singular.

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, choose an eigenvector $x$ for this eigenvalue, and normalize $x$ so that $x^Hx=1$. Then
$$ \lambda =\lambda(x^Hx)=x^H(\lambda x)=x^HAx>0 $$
so $\lambda$ is a positive real number.

Comment: I don't know why $(Cx)^HCx > 0$

Comment: $y^Hy=|y_1|^2+\dots+|y_n|^2>0$ for every non-zero vector $y$. Set $y=Cx$.

Comment: What does mean $|y_1|$ ? For me $y^Hy$ is $y_1^2+..+y_n^2$. Do you use fact that non-singular matrix multiplied by  non-zero vector give non-zero vector ?

Comment: $|y_1|$ is the absolute value of the complex number $y_1$. Yes, $Cx$ is non-zero because $C$ is non-singular.

Comment: so $|y_1|^2 = y_1^2$.  From what you know that $x^Hx = 1 $ ? (when $x$ is normalized. Moreover, from what you know that $x^HAx$ is real ?

Comment: $|y_1|^2$ is *not* the same as $y_1^2$. What if $y_1=i$? Given any non-zero vector $x$, it can always be normalized so that $x^Hx=1$, by dividing by $\sqrt{x^Hx}$. And the first part of my answer showed that $x^HAx>0$.

Comment: Ok, from what you knwo that $\lambda(x^Hx) = x^H(\lambda x) = x^HAx$

Comment: The first equality is just linearity of the inner product. The second is because $Ax=\lambda x$.

Comment: "The first equality is just linearity of the inner product" What do you mean ?

Comment: The inner product $x^Hy$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$ is linear (strictly speaking, sesqui-linear) in that $(x+y)^Hz=x^Hz+y^Hz$ for all vectors $x,y,z$, and $(\lambda x)^Hy=\overline{\lambda}x^Hy$, and $x^H(\lambda y)=\lambda x^Hy$ for any scalar $\lambda$.